# sifr 2.0.7 only working when font is installed on user's computer?

Tags: flash, sifr

Hey all.  I am using sifr 2.0.7 and here's the deal. The sifr is working (I can see it in the DOM) however, the font is wrong.  It doesn't pick up my swf font (DIN) unless you have it installed on your computer?  The css font style is: HelveticaNeue which is what the sifr seems to render if you don't have DIN installed.  I see it on my computer but my friend see DIN.  Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you've properly embedded DIN inside the sifr swf.  If the font isn't embedded there, Flash will fallback to a font installed on the user's system.

The [sifr docs](http://wiki.novemberborn.net/sifr/How+to+use) have some more details on this.

Comment: Would this cause Flash to fallback to using DIN?  Even though it isn't defined in the stylesheet?  Thanks.